# Why does this emoji have len of 2 on windows(python)?

Tags: python, unicode

**On windows:**

```
>>> a = u'\U0001f649'
>>> print a

>>> len(a)
2
>>> a[0]
u'\ud83d'
>>> a[1]
u'\ude49'
```

**On linux:**

```
>>> a = u'\U0001f649'
>>> print a

>>> len(a)
1
>>> a[0]
u'\U0001f649'
```

So how come `\U0001f649` is converted to `\ud83d` and `\ude49` on windows? And could somebody thoroughly explain the whole relation/connection between them? Also, how do you convert `\U0001f649` to `\ud83d` and `\ude49` on Linux?

**P.S.**: Both on Python 2.6.6

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
```

Comment: What are the Python version numbers?

Comment: Short version: UCS-4 vs UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: python 2.6.6. And honestly I do want to know the realtionship between `\U0001f649` and `\ud83d` + `\ude49`, and how does it work?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

Comment: @Max How do I convert them back and forth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because these two versions are compiled with different native encodings.  The Windows version is using UTF-16 internally, and the Linux version is using UCS-4/UTF-32 internally.

You can see the difference:

On windows, and OSX:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxunicode
65535
```

On Linux, you will get 1114112, I think.

This means each character takes 2 bytes on Windows, and 4 bytes on Linux.  If the character does not fit, because it is higher than 65536, it is encoded in UTF-16.

For your question, you can see the two different encodings by doing this:

```
[UTF-16]
>>> a = u'\U0001f649'
>>> [hex(ord(x)) for x in a.encode('utf-16be')]  # UTF-16, Big Endian
['0xd8', '0x3d', '0xde', '0x49']
```

Which corresponds to \ud83d\ude49, as you see on Windows.

```
[UTF-32]
>>> [hex(ord(x)) for x in a.encode('utf-32be')] # UTF-32, Big Endian
['0x0', '0x1', '0xf6', '0x49']
```

Which corresponds to \U0001F649, as you see on Linux.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) has a fairly extensive article on UTF-16, but basically, part of the code space was set aside, and ten bits of the full 20 bit number are encoded in each word.

As a side note, later versions of Python 3 do away with this altogether.  Rather than having every string either be 16 bit or 32 bit depending on compile time option: each string is 8-bit, 16-bit, or 32-bit depending on the largest character in the string.  This is much more efficient as most of the strings in a program are ASCII, or Basic Multilingual Plane only.

Comment: Wouldn't those two `encode` calls give the same results regardless of the underlying internal representation?

Comment: Yes, he asked how to change from one to the other, so I provided a demonstration.